# Why SABRE is returning "MIN CONNECTION TIME NOT MET BEFORE LEG 2"

Tags: rest, soap, sabre

In my BFM Rest request, I can find a flight. In my BFM Soap request (Bargain Finder Max RQ) I can´t find the same flight. Sometimes BFM Soap Sabre is returning: "MIN CONNECTION TIME NOT MET BEFORE LEG 2". Whys is this happening?

This is my request to BFM SOAP:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" Version="3.3.0" ResponseType="OTA" ResponseVersion="3.3.0">
  <POS xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <Source PseudoCityCode="">
      <RequestorID Type="1" ID="1">
        <CompanyName Code="TN" />
      </RequestorID>
    </Source>
  </POS>
  <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="0" Fixed="true" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <DepartureDateTime>2018-01-31T06:50:00</DepartureDateTime>
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="BSB" />
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CNF" />
    <TPA_Extensions>
      <Flight Number="3349" DepartureDateTime="2018-01-31T06:50:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-01-31T08:10:00" Type="A">
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="BSB" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="CNF" />
        <Airline Operating="JJ" Marketing="JJ" />
        <Fare BrandID="JJ" />
      </Flight>
      <ConnectionTime Min="115" />
    </TPA_Extensions>
  </OriginDestinationInformation>
  <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="1" Fixed="true" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <DepartureDateTime>2018-01-31T10:05:00</DepartureDateTime>
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="CNF" />
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="GRU" />
    <TPA_Extensions>
      <Flight Number="3345" DepartureDateTime="2018-01-31T10:05:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-01-31T11:20:00" Type="A">
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="CNF" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="GRU" />
        <Airline Operating="JJ" Marketing="JJ" />
        <Fare BrandID="JJ" />
      </Flight>
      <ConnectionTime Min="60" />
    </TPA_Extensions>
  </OriginDestinationInformation>
  <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="2" Fixed="true" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <DepartureDateTime>2018-02-21T16:50:00</DepartureDateTime>
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="GRU" />
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="GYN" />
    <TPA_Extensions>
      <Flight Number="3546" DepartureDateTime="2018-02-21T16:50:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-02-21T18:31:00" Type="A">
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="GRU" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="GYN" />
        <Airline Operating="JJ" Marketing="JJ" />
        <Fare BrandID="JJ" />
      </Flight>
      <ConnectionTime Min="169" />
    </TPA_Extensions>
  </OriginDestinationInformation>
  <OriginDestinationInformation RPH="3" Fixed="true" xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <DepartureDateTime>2018-02-21T21:20:00</DepartureDateTime>
    <OriginLocation LocationCode="GYN" />
    <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BSB" />
    <TPA_Extensions>
      <Flight Number="3854" DepartureDateTime="2018-02-21T21:20:00" ArrivalDateTime="2018-02-21T22:00:00" Type="A">
        <OriginLocation LocationCode="GYN" />
        <DestinationLocation LocationCode="BSB" />
        <Airline Operating="JJ" Marketing="JJ" />
        <Fare BrandID="JJ" />
      </Flight>
      <ConnectionTime Min="60" />
    </TPA_Extensions>
  </OriginDestinationInformation>
  <TravelPreferences xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <TPA_Extensions>
      <NumTrips Number="1" />
      <TripType />
      <XOFares Value="false" />
    </TPA_Extensions>
  </TravelPreferences>
  <TravelerInfoSummary xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <SeatsRequested>1</SeatsRequested>
    <AirTravelerAvail>
      <PassengerTypeQuantity Code="ADT" Quantity="1" />
    </AirTravelerAvail>
  </TravelerInfoSummary>
  <TPA_Extensions xmlns="http://www.opentravel.org/OTA/2003/05">
    <IntelliSellTransaction>
      <RequestType Name="50ITINS" />
    </IntelliSellTransaction>
    <DiversityControl>
      <LowFareBucket Options="20%" FareCutOff="25%" />
      <Dimensions>
        <Carrier Weight="1" OnlineIndicator="true" />
      </Dimensions>
    </DiversityControl>
  </TPA_Extensions>
</OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ>
```

The min connection time is 60 min. 
The flight connection time is greater than 60 min.

Answer (score 1):

Normally have a minimum connection Time is needed between the arrival and departure of 2 segments depending on Airline and Airport.  E.g. you cant arrive at 1:30 PM and departe 1:35 PM.

It seems the time is too small (can be checked when booking the itin in Sabre RED with VCT*).

Regarding the discrepancy it sounds like a case for sabre support. In general i dont trust SABRE Rest, so i trust Soap to be correct.

If you want to you can give me the segments and i will check on the Sabre Workspace.

Comment: Thank you Thomas for your response. I´ve put the request json in the body of the question.

Answer (score 1):

In xml OTA_AirLowFareSearchRQ there is an object called OriginDestinetionInformation and inside this object there another property called OriginDestinetionInformation. If you set THE property "Fixed" to false maybe this error will be solved. I´m yet testing this solution.